# Getting undefined in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently learning APIs and calling them using XMLHttpRequest. I am also trying to use JSON.parse...hopefully correctly. However when used in my program it's returning undefined, so my displayQuote is working, it's just not able to return my data.

I've been having some difficulties with logic structure, so I can't figure it out! Any help or hints as to why I'm not receiving the data parsed into author and text would be very helpful.

```
var getQuote = new XMLHttpRequest();
getQuote.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (getQuote.readyState == 4 && getQuote.status == 200) {

  var arrObj = JSON.parse(getQuote.responseText);
  author = arrObj.title;
  text = arrObj.content; 
  displayQuote();
```

Comment: What's in `getQuote` at that point?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a json? Ajax call would be come in handy

Comment: What does `displayQuote` do? is `arrObj` an array, and if so, why are you not saying something like `arrObj[0]`?

Comment: That was exactly it torazaburo. I didn't realize the array was within another array. Thank you so much. I'll be more attentive in the future.